# script bash Linux don't find error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to verify in a script bash that a folder exists. The problem is, it does but the script tells me that my file does not exist.

I don't find the error and I have searched on the internet and I do exactly the way it says to do( on Openclassroom, forum, ...).

here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ] && [ -d $1 ]; then
        echo "Usage : $0 dir">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
fi
backup="~/backup"
echo $backup , argument = $1
if [ ! -e ${backup} ]; then
        echo "Le dossier backup n'existe pas">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d $backup ]; then
        echo "le document backup n'est pas un fichier">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
fi
if [ -w $backup ]; then
        echo "Le dossier backup n'est pas protégé en écriture">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
fi
 il qu$if [! chmod u=+w $backup ]; then
        echo "une erreur c'est produite">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
fi
```

And what it said in the shell + the proof that the file backup exist in the correct repertory:

```
guy@PC-DE-GUY:~/bash/Chap9$ ./backup.sh ~/seance06/
    ~/backup , argument = /home/guy/seance06/
    Le dossier backup n'existe pas

guy@PC-DE-GUY:~/bash/Chap9$ ~/backup
    bash: /home/guy/backup : est un dossier

guy@PC-DE-GUY:~/bash/Chap9$ cd ~/backup

guy@PC-DE-GUY:~/backup$
```

Comment: `~` does not expand within double-quotes, remove it or use `$HOME`, i.e. `backup=~/backup` or `backup="${HOME}/backup"`

Comment: Some hint:  I always promote using double quotes when evaluating shell variables, so better always use `"$backup"` instead of `$backup` (because otherwise if `$backup` contains strange characters like spaces, the shell might split that up and make two parameters out of this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `~` character inside quotes, in `backup="~/backup"` (line 6). BASH processes it as a character, not as an alias to your home directory, so your code runs the checks on the string `'~/backup'`, instead of `'/home/guy/backup'`.

To use `~` as an alias to your home directory, it should be outside quotes: `backup=~/backup`

If you want to hardcode your home directory, I suggest you use `$HOME` instead of `~`. It's clearer to understand.

You can test what I tried to explain with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Save this file as test.sh
# run this script with ~ as an argument:
# ./test.sh ~

echo "Value for \$HOME: $HOME"
echo "Value for ~ inside quotes: ~"
echo "Value for ~ outside quotes:" ~
echo "Value for \$1: $1"
```

If you save the code above as `test.sh` and you run it as: `./test.sh ~`, outputs will be:

```
Value for $HOME: /home/guy
Value for ~ inside quotes: ~
Value for ~ outside quotes: /home/guy
Value for $1: /home/guy
```